# MVC pattern; my model class needs user input, but I know it shouldn't ask either the user or the controller

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller

I am creating a simple Blackjack game making use of the MVC pattern.

The main controller is called `Game`, the main view is called `BlackjackView` and the implementation of it that I am currently using is `ConsoleView`, the main model class is called `Blackjack`.

Here is some simplified code where I don't understand how to implement the next part:

Game.java

```
public class Game {
    private Blackjack blackjack;
    private BlackjackView view;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        blackjack = Blackjack.initializeGame();
        view = new ConsoleView(blackjack);

        blackjack.takeTurns();
    }
}
```

Blackjack.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Blackjack {
    private List<Person> players = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public static Blackjack initializeGame() {
        return new Blackjack();
    }

    public void takeTurns() {
        for (Person player : players) {
            // ask player to 'hit' or 'stay'
        }
    }
}
```

I can't comprehend how to do this, as `Blackjack` should have nothing to do with asking the user something or getting user input.

As I understand correctly, my view class has to display the question ('Player, do you want to hit or stay?') and my controller class has to handle the input.

I thought of passing a reference to `Game` to `Blackjack`, so I can ask it to ask the user for input, but I know I'm not supposed to do that.

Comment: Why don't pass the view to the blackjack so that it can ask the view to get input from the user?

Comment: The model should not have any knowledge of the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually created a controller or a view, based on what you show us. The model shouldn't "ask" anyone for anything. It's a choose-and-tell process.

The input view *tells* the controller what inputs are offered. The controller chooses the model instance, then *tells* the model what inputs to process. The controller then chooses the next view, then *tells* the view what model instance it used. The view then *asks* the model for results, and formats the results according to the view logic. That view then either awaits input or invokes an input view to do so. The cycle repeats.

Comment: Alright, I kind of understand it now. However, to me it made more sense if this sequence starts with your second sentence: "The controller chooses the model instance, ..." Is this correct?
I have used your answer to finish this project, which is [posted here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/simple-blackjack-game-in-console-update)

Comment: How would the controller choose the model instance without knowing what needs to be done?